# Target class [Eraufi\Src\GenerateCRUDCommand] does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

I've created a Package for Laravel and published it to https://packagist.org/.

In Laravel framework I've downloaded it using compser `composer require eraufi/crud`

now when I run `composer dump-autoload` I get this error  `Target class [Eraufi\Src\GenerateCRUDCommand] does not exist.`

I've Asked ChatGPT as well but got no luck.

app\Console\Kernel.php:

```
namespace App\Console;

use Eraufi\Src\GenerateCRUDCommand;
use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{    
    protected $commands = [
        GenerateCRUDCommand::class,
    ];
}
```

vendor\eraufi\crud\composer.json

```
{
    "name": "eraufi/crud",
    "description": "A package for generating CRUD operations in Laravel",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Mohufi",
            "email": "ed@gg.com"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.1",
        "laravel/framework": "^10.10"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "eraufi\\crud\\": "src/"
        }
    }
}
```

vendor\eraufi\crud\src\GenerateCRUDCommand.php

```
<?php

namespace Eraufi\Crud;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Support\Str; // Import the Str class
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;


use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class GenerateCRUDCommand extends Command
{
    protected $signature = 'crud:generate {model}';

    protected $description = 'Generate CRUD operations for a model based on the database table';

    public function handle()
    {
        $model = $this->argument('model');
        $tableName = Str::snake($model);
        $question = [
            'generateView' => $this->confirm('Generate Views?'),
            'isEducationl' => $this->confirm('Are you Using this for Educational Purposes? (Adds Comments)'),
        ];
        $columns = Schema::getColumnListing($tableName);

        $this->requestCodes($model, $columns, $question);
        $this->controllerCodes($model, $columns, $question);

        $this->routeCodes($model, $question);
        if ($question['generateView']) {
            $this->indexViewCodes($model, $columns);
            $this->createViewCodes($model);
            $this->createEditCodes($model);
            $this->createShowCodes($model);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As far as I know namespaces and classes are case sensitive so your PSR-4 in composer.json should be `"Eraufi\\Crud\\": "src/"`

Comment: thanks for the comment i've updated my composer.json file still getting same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the `composer.json` is referencing `\\eraufi\\crud` but the file is using `namespace Eraufi\Src`, it should be `namespace Eraufi\crud` (and use the propper case, `Eraufi\Crud`...)

Comment: thanks for your answer i updated my namespace still getting same error.
i even updated the question in here

Comment: @MohammadEdrisRaufi you still did not change `use Eraufi\Src\GenerateCRUDCommand;` to `use Eraufi\Crud\GenerateCRUDCommand;`... How are you doing this? locally? it must be done from the package and then you have to run `composer update`.